# Best way to handle multiple sockets in Qt server application?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, network-programming

I'm making a simple client server program for a school project in Qt, but I've run into problems on how to handle multiple new connections to the server. The code I have for new connections so far is pretty basic:

```
void LoginServer::newConnection()
{
   logSock = server->nextPendingConnection();

   if(!logSock->waitForConnected(500))
   {
       qDebug() << "Connection failed";
   }else
   {
       qDebug() << "It worked!";
       connect(logSock, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(readData()));
   }
}
```

One method I saw on the internet was pushing new connections to a data structure such as a vector, and handling them from the one container. One issue I have with this is if so I connect all the different sockets to the same slot for reading data, is there any elegant way to tell which socket sent the signal?

Another way I considered doing it was that when readyRead() was emitted, I could search through the list of sockets to see which had bytesAvailable, but that seems like an overly simplistic solution to me. Plus, if two sockets sent data at the same time the program might identify the wrong socket.

Another option I considered was overriding readyRead() to include a reference to itself in the signal, and then I realized that I don't have the first idea how to do that.

```
connect(logSock, SIGNAL(readyRead(QTcpSocket*)),this, SLOT(readData(QTcpSocket*)));
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify the socket, which emitted readyRead() signal by using the following code in the slot:

```
QTcpSocket* socket = qobject_cast< QTcpSocket* >(sender());
```

...and read the data by 
`socket->readAll()`.
`sender()` returns the pointer to QObject, which emit the signal.